# Force passage from default switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a switch where for particular cases I need to do some peculiar things but I still want them to pass through the default case of the switch statement because in there I have functionality that is common to all cases. How can I force the passage to the default case after I've handled the peculiar one?

Example:

```
    switch(someVar) {
        case "a":
            ....
            //do something peculiar for a 
            break;
        case "b":
            ...
            //do something peculiar for b
            break;
        default: 
            ...
            //common things that all cases should do
    }
```

At the moment I've just copy-pasted the lines inside the default at the bottom of each peculiar case but that's ugly.

Comment: If those statements are must, why not take them out of switch case

Comment: good point... not supposed to refactor that much though.

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao also, not all the peculiar cases need those "default" lines

Comment: @knittl yeah just extract a method and call it from the default case. seems right thanks

Comment: It wouldn't be good refactoring at all if something like this is achieved. Default is only supposed to run if none of other cases occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If things must be executed unconditionally, they should be moved out of the condition:

```
switch(someVar) {
    case "a":
        ....
        //do something peculiar for a 
        break;
    case "b":
        ...
        //do something peculiar for b
        break;
}

//common things that all cases should do
```

Alternatively, extract a method:

```
switch(someVar) {
    case "a":
        ....
        //do something peculiar for a 
        doCommonThings();
        break;
    case "b":
        ...
        //do something peculiar for b
        doCommonThings();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a thing is common for all cases it should ring a warning that it is not supposed to be in a switch-case at all, but be moved outside.

```
switch(someVar) {
    case "a":
        ....
        //do something peculiar for a 
        break;
    case "b":
        ...
        //do something peculiar for b
        break;
}

//common things that all cases should do
```

Similar to as if you would do for an if else

```
if(isSpecial) {
    do X
}
else {
    do Y
}
do for both
```

Not

```
if(isSpecial) {
    do X
    do for both
}
else {
    do Y
    do for both
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If something you want should be executed at all conditions, the best choice would be to put that just outside the switch case.

```
   switch(someVar) {
    case "a":
        ....
        break;
    case "b":
        ...
        break;
    default: 
        ...
    }
{commmon things to be executed}
```

Ideally, **default** statement is to just execute when none of your cases match.